# Expose scss mixins through webpack ModuleFederationPlugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-module-federation

How to expose scss mixins through webpack ModuleFederationPlugin which can be exposed to other remote MicroFrontends in react app.
I have tried exposing like this

```
ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: 'ShellApp',
            filename: 'js/shell-app-entry.js',
            exposes: {
                './SharedMixins': './src/config/theme/core/_mixins.scss'
            }})
```

and then in the remote MFE imported it but when i used the mixins in the scss file over remote App it says mixin is undefined